# How to set wirble colorize on XP

Tags: windows, ruby

I'm having problems setting up wirble on XP machine. when i run IRB i get sth like this:

> > "foo".capitalize
> >     => ←[0;31m"←[0;0m←[0;36mFoo←[0;0m←[0;31m"←[0;0m

this occurs only if I call colorize on wirble either in .irbrc or after starting irb. I installed ruby 1.8.6 with the all-in-one installer. Any ideas on how to get colors working?

Comment: using win32console gem solves the color problems, but creates new ones: like when navigating through command history when one command is longer than another, it leaves garbege on the screen (eg.: wirble.colorize then exit gives: >> exit        ize

Comment: @dahpgjgamgan, The garbage problem seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 5):

First install these two gems:

```
gem install win32console
gem install wirble
```

Then in your irb console do:

```
require 'win32console'
include Win32::Console::ANSI
require 'wirble'
Wirble.init
Wirble.colorize
```

Your input will look corectly:

```
"foo".capitalize
=> "Foo"
```

(Foo is in blue on my screen now)

P.S.
If you want irb always to start with these settings just put the above code in the '.irbrc' file in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://www.botvector.net/2008/06/colorized-wirble-in-windows-xp.html

(which was the first Google hit for "wirble windows")